# What to use instead of GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector?

Tags: java, neo4j, bolt

I'm using Neo4j's Java driver to access the db with Bolt protocol.

If I have a look at the [Neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded-bolt), I see that I should use `GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector` for settings.

However my IDE says it's deprecated.

Do you know what replaces `GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector`?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify : are you in embedded or remote mode ?

Comment: In the "production mode" I'm in remote mode. In my tests I try to create an embedded database and there I need some settings. I try to do something similiar to this:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/blob/master/neo4j-jdbc-bolt/src/test/java/org/neo4j/jdbc/bolt/Neo4jBoltRule.java

Comment: So why are you not using the `Neo4jRul`e from `neo4j-harness` ? The bolt connection is free with it.  The JDBC driver have been written at the same time than this rule, that's why it not using it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make it work. So far I have such a problem:
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/gzip/GzipHandler
Although my pom includes jetty-server. Have you faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a error in the docs. [The docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector.html) about `GraphDatabaseSettings.BoltConnector` says:

> DEPRECATED: **Use BoltConnector instead.** This will be removed in 4.0.

That is: `BoltConnector` is deprecated, so use `BoltConnector` instead. (???)

Comment: It make sense if you look at the source code, and note the generated java doc : `DEPRECATED: Use {@link org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.BoltConnector} instead. This will be removed in 4.0.`. 
So :  stop using the inline class BoltConnector, and use the class BoltConnector :)